# Registros repetidos en ListView Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-listview

Tengo una vista donde listo un resultado que obtengo de mi base de datos y pasa que cuando se pasa de cantidad de elementos y empieza a funcionar el scroll empieza a pasar cosas extrañas con mi lista de elementos cosas como:

1 - se duplican registros (aveces si a veces no) según utilice el scroll. Como podrán ver en las imágenes el mismo registro aparece 2 veces y en la base de datos lo tengo una sola ves, incluso si hago mucho movimiento de scroll de momento es otro el elemento que se duplica algo aleatorio.

[image: va]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les comparto los códigos donde creo se puede apreciar como cargo el **ListView**:

Activity:

// Construct AlertDialog
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

```
            // load view
            LayoutInflater inflaterTemp = this.getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflaterTemp.inflate(R.layout.dialog_last_dte, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
// Open connection local (Ticket)
            DSTicket DSTicket = new DSTicket(getApplicationContext());
            List<ModelTicket> tickets = DSTicket.listSend(DateHelper.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            String total = DSTicket.sum("2");
            String totalCanceled = DSTicket.sumCanceled("2");
            DSTicket.close();

            // load totals in view
            TextView ammount = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ammount);
            if(total.equals("null")){
                total = "0.00";
            } else {
                total = String.valueOf(CalculatorHelper.ajustAmmount(Float.valueOf(total)));
            }
            ammount.setText("Total ventas: " + total + " $");

            TextView ammountCanceled = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ammountCanceled);
            if(totalCanceled.equals("null")){
                totalCanceled = "0.00";
            } else {
                totalCanceled = String.valueOf(CalculatorHelper.ajustAmmount(Float.valueOf(totalCanceled)));
            }
            ammountCanceled.setText("Total anulado: " + totalCanceled + " $");

            ListView listViewTickets = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            Adapter adapter = new AdapterTicket(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.this, (ArrayList<ModelTicket>) tickets);
            listViewTickets.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
```

Adapter:

```
public class AdapterTicket extends ArrayAdapter<ModelTicket>{

    private ArrayList<ModelTicket> m_dataSet;
    Context m_context;
    Activity m_activity;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView MsgRow;
        TextView Ticket;
        Button ButtonReprint;
        Button ButtonCancel;
    }

    public AdapterTicket(Context context, Activity activity, ArrayList<ModelTicket> data) {
        super(context, R.layout.dialog_last_dte_ticket, data);
        this.m_dataSet = data;
        this.m_context = context;
        this.m_activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the data item for this position
        final ModelTicket ticketModel = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_last_dte_ticket, null);

            viewHolder.Ticket = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticket);
            viewHolder.ButtonReprint = convertView.findViewById(R.id.reprint);
            viewHolder.ButtonCancel = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            viewHolder.MsgRow = convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgRow);
            viewHolder.Ticket.setText("$"+ ticketModel.getM_mnttotal() +" \n " + ticketModel.getM_houremis());

            if(ticketModel.getM_folio().equals(ticketModel.getM_nota_folioref())){
                viewHolder.ButtonReprint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                viewHolder.ButtonCancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                viewHolder.MsgRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            // capture click in row
            /*
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Fila: " + ticketModel.getM_folio());
                }
            });
            */

            // capture click in button reprint
            viewHolder.ButtonReprint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // generate ticket
                    Intent printTicket = new Intent(m_activity, PrintTicketActivity.class);
                    printTicket.putExtra("ticketId", String.valueOf(ticketModel.getM_id()));
                    printTicket.putExtra("dirpath", "reprint");
                    m_context.startActivity(printTicket);
                }
            });

            // capture click in cancel
            viewHolder.ButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // generate nota de crédito
                    Intent cancelTicket = new Intent(m_activity, CancelTicketActivity.class);
                    cancelTicket.putExtra("ticketId", String.valueOf(ticketModel.getM_id()));

                    // Open connection local (Ticket)
                    DSTicket DSTicket = new DSTicket(m_context);
                    String[] data = new String[9];

                    // save cancel ticket
                    data[0] = String.valueOf(getCaf("61").getM_id());          // NOTA_CAFID
                    data[1] = getCaf("61").getM_documenttype();                // NOTA_TIPODTE
                    data[2] = getCaf("61").getM_rng_a();                       // NOTA_FOLIO
                    data[3] = ticketModel.getM_folio();                                     // NOTA_FOLIOREF
                    data[4] = ticketModel.getM_tipodte();                                   // NOTA_TIPODTEREF
                    data[5] = ticketModel.getM_nota_cafidref();                             // NOTA_CAFIDREF
                    data[6] = "1";                                                          // ANULA_RAZONREF [1, DEV D LA BOLETA],[2, COR GIRO DEL RECP], [3, DEV DE MERC]
                    data[7] = DateHelper.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");        // ANULA_RAZONREF
                    data[8] = "ANULA BOLETA";                                               // ANULA_RAZONREF
                    boolean resultTicket = DSTicket.cancel(ticketModel.getM_id(), data);
                    DSTicket.close();

                    // increment +1 rang used
                    incrementCaf("61");

                    // activity for generate PDF
                    m_context.startActivity(cancelTicket);
                }
            });

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    /*
     * Get data to CAF from DB LOCAL
     **/
    public ModelCaf getCaf(String documenttype){

        // get caf local database
        DSCaf DSCaf = new DSCaf(m_context);
        ModelCaf resultCaf = DSCaf.get(documenttype);
        DSCaf.close();

        return resultCaf;
    }

    /*
     * Increment CAF +1
     **/
    public boolean incrementCaf(String documenttype){

        // get caf local database
        DSCaf DSCaf = new DSCaf(m_context);
        boolean resultCaf = DSCaf.increment(documenttype);
        DSCaf.close();

        return resultCaf;
    }

}
```

Gracias de antemano espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Bueno no me había dado cuenta en la imagen el registro de $800 también se repite y el de 1090 igual.

Answer (score 1):

```
      public AdapterTicket(Context context, Activity activity, ArrayList<ModelTicket> data) {
            super(context, R.layout.dialog_last_dte_ticket, data);
            this.m_dataSet = data;
            this.m_context = context;
            this.m_activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // Get the data item for this position
            final ModelTicket ticketModel = getItem(position);

            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

            if (convertView == null) {

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_last_dte_ticket, null);

                viewHolder.Ticket = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticket);
                viewHolder.ButtonReprint = convertView.findViewById(R.id.reprint);
                viewHolder.ButtonCancel = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                viewHolder.MsgRow = convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgRow);


                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

} else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


                // capture click in row
                /*
                convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Fila: " + ticketModel.getM_folio());
                    }
                });
                */

                // capture click in button reprint
                viewHolder.ButtonReprint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // generate ticket
                        Intent printTicket = new Intent(m_activity, PrintTicketActivity.class);
                        printTicket.putExtra("ticketId", String.valueOf(ticketModel.getM_id()));
                        printTicket.putExtra("dirpath", "reprint");
                        m_context.startActivity(printTicket);
                    }
                });

                // capture click in cancel
                viewHolder.ButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // generate nota de crédito
                        Intent cancelTicket = new Intent(m_activity, CancelTicketActivity.class);
                        cancelTicket.putExtra("ticketId", String.valueOf(ticketModel.getM_id()));

                        // Open connection local (Ticket)
                        DSTicket DSTicket = new DSTicket(m_context);
                        String[] data = new String[9];

                        // save cancel ticket
                        data[0] = String.valueOf(getCaf("61").getM_id());          // NOTA_CAFID
                        data[1] = getCaf("61").getM_documenttype();                // NOTA_TIPODTE
                        data[2] = getCaf("61").getM_rng_a();                       // NOTA_FOLIO
                        data[3] = ticketModel.getM_folio();                                     // NOTA_FOLIOREF
                        data[4] = ticketModel.getM_tipodte();                                   // NOTA_TIPODTEREF
                        data[5] = ticketModel.getM_nota_cafidref();                             // NOTA_CAFIDREF
                        data[6] = "1";                                                          // ANULA_RAZONREF [1, DEV D LA BOLETA],[2, COR GIRO DEL RECP], [3, DEV DE MERC]
                        data[7] = DateHelper.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");        // ANULA_RAZONREF
                        data[8] = "ANULA BOLETA";                                               // ANULA_RAZONREF
                        boolean resultTicket = DSTicket.cancel(ticketModel.getM_id(), data);
                        DSTicket.close();

                        // increment +1 rang used
                        incrementCaf("61");

                        // activity for generate PDF
                        m_context.startActivity(cancelTicket);
                    }
                });



viewHolder.Ticket.setText("$"+ ticketModel.getM_mnttotal() +" \n " + ticketModel.getM_houremis());

                if(ticketModel.getM_folio().equals(ticketModel.getM_nota_folioref())){
                    viewHolder.ButtonReprint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.ButtonCancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.MsgRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            return convertView;
        }


        /*
         * Get data to CAF from DB LOCAL
         **/
        public ModelCaf getCaf(String documenttype){

            // get caf local database
            DSCaf DSCaf = new DSCaf(m_context);
            ModelCaf resultCaf = DSCaf.get(documenttype);
            DSCaf.close();

            return resultCaf;
        }

        /*
         * Increment CAF +1
         **/
        public boolean incrementCaf(String documenttype){

            // get caf local database
            DSCaf DSCaf = new DSCaf(m_context);
            boolean resultCaf = DSCaf.increment(documenttype);
            DSCaf.close();

            return resultCaf;
        }

    }
```

revisalo.

Answer (score 0):

Amigos solucioné el problema limpiando la variable convertView antes de comparar en el if, para que siempre entre allí.

```
convertView = null;
```

antes del:

```
if (convertView == null) {
```

No se si es la mejor solución o si pueda tener anomalías futuras. De igual forma por el momento es mi mejor solución.

Comment: esa no es la solución apropiada.. para tal caso no uses el convertView,   busca como se realiza correctamente un listado con viewholder.

Comment: tienes que separar los viewHolder.Ticket = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticket); de los viewHolder.Ticket.setText("$"+ ticketModel.getM_mnttotal() +" \n " + ticketModel.getM_houremis());